# EXCEL: Calculate a specific range of cells or current selection

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible in Excel to calculate only a certain range of cells,

Even if it is just the range selected for example.

I have a workbook that has all sorts going on.

To make it more efficient I have calculations set to manual.

Then hit F9 whenever I need to refresh, however, this can still take some time to calculate, (well over 10 mins)

Is it possible for me to select Cells `A1:B10`, and some how just refresh the formulas in this range ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just wanted to illustrate a non-VBA alternative:

[image]

- All cell in `A1:C6` have formula `=RANDBETWEEN(1,10)`
- Calculation set to manual

Select a range, say `A1:B4` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, find and replace all `=` with `=`, confirm.

[image]

If you go VBA-route then @Akina has the correct answer for you. I just want to add to that, it may be usefull to create a custom tab on the ribbon to assign the macro to. For example:

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant for a non VBA answer, I would actually upvote this twice for the custom ribbon idea, I already have a custom ribbon tab, but surprisingly hardly anyone else does this !

Comment: @PeterH, I'm glad it helped you out :). However, it does involve some VBA ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
Worksheets("SheetName").Range("A1:B10").Calculate
```

Create a macro with this code line and set it to a knob and/or a hotkey.

> Is it possible to change Range("A1:B10") to Range.Selection ?

Range have no `Selection` property, but it is of Range type itself. Use simple

```
Selection.Calculate
```

If you mean "selection in some range" then use `Intersect()` function to obtain the range within both specified range and selection.